# Oauth2 API authentication using cli

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

I am using thephpleague/oauth2-client to consume AngelList API, I want to automate the process through CLI, may final objective to make search for specific startups and store the information in db. I want this process to run every two hours so I thought I can use CLI and cron as scheduler. but I can't get the token_code as I have to be redirected to a web page.

I hope you can share some of your ideas to make this happen

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a `client_credentials` grant to obtain a token from the Authorization Server (if that is supported), or you can try and get an `access_token` plus a `refresh_token` once through a regular `code` grant that involves a browser, but have the client use the `refresh_token` to obtain new `access_tokens`'s autonomously (through what is called the `refresh_token` grant) when the original `access_token` expires.